# Drupal 9 Module Installation Error: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later

Tags: php, drupal, module

I'm currently new to Drupal. I always wanted to work and learn more about drupal and thats when I decided to locally host a project on my windows 10 Using Xampp. I'm currenly using the lastest drupal version and after a couple of issues with Xampp and other minor issues I was able to setup drupal.

However, after trying to install few modules my website started showing me the following error. I'm not able to access to my admin page or any other page on my site to check what went wrong. However, after searching for solutions I was able to get the error message and I'm posting it below so you guys can help me figure out the issue.

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "entity.workspace.collection" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 206 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider.php).
Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->getRoute('entity.workspace.collection') (Line: 271)
Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->generateFromRoute('entity.workspace.collection', Array, Array, 1) (Line: 105)
Drupal\Core\Render\MetadataBubblingUrlGenerator->generateFromRoute('entity.workspace.collection', Array, Array, 1) (Line: 762)
Drupal\Core\Url->toString(1) (Line: 182)
Drupal\Core\Utility\LinkGenerator->generate(Object, Object) (Line: 95)
Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Link::preRenderLink(Array)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 101)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725', 'exception', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 781)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 372)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 444)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 93)
template_preprocess_toolbar(Array, 'toolbar', Array) (Line: 287)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('toolbar', Array) (Line: 431)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 444)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 450)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array, 'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 82)
__TwigTemplate_6a4b51e0b4776d6f542ec8cc68c4b9f9a90987b4820efe11ebf41652512d53df->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 405)
Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 390)
Twig\Template->render(Array) (Line: 65)
twig_render_template('core/themes/seven/templates/classy/layout/html.html.twig', Array) (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('html', Array) (Line: 431)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 162)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 163)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 142)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object, 'kernel.view') (Line: 163)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 80)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 706)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Comment: What modules have you installed? it would be useful to identify which one is causing this problem, aka install one at time to see which one causes the problem. Because from the log I'd say it could be "workspace"  but there is not a D9 version, so... Anyway, have you emptied your cache after installing the modules? `drush cr` to do it via drush

Comment: It was caused by workspaces and media. I haven't installed drush but im trying to install drush now. Since im a newbie its taking time for me to learn.